# Custom Sorting According to custom class in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a two classes which can be a child.

RMTerm and RMFile. A RMTerm list can contains both RMTerm and RMFile

Well I want to sort this list 2 times.

Firstly, in my list, first RMFile items and then RMTerm items

I did that.

```
_term.Childs = _term.Childs.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().Name).ToList();
```

but after that in the list, RMFile has children that is a different class and i need to sort by these children property.

```
 _term.Childs.OfType<RMFile>().OrderBy(o => o.Childs.All(a => a.Properties["ActiveStatus"]
.Equals("C"))).ToList();
```

ActiveStatus property can be O,C or R. I want to sort like if all children's ActiveStatus are "C" then this RMFile item must be end of the list. If one of RMFile's children are not "C" then it must be top or at leeast further than the RMFile which has completly "C" children.

This code seems OK

```
  _term.Childs.OfType<RMFile>().OrderBy(o => o.Childs.All(a => a.Properties["ActiveStatus"]
   .Equals("C"))).ToList();
```

but the problem how to combine with the previous one. Because Childs can be RMTerm or RMFile.

Shortly I need to do something like

```
_term.Childs = _term.Childs.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().Name).OfType<RMFile>()
.ThenBy(o => o.Childs.All(a => a.Properties["ActiveStatus"].Equals("C"))).ToList();
```

but I cant do that because  casts the items

UPDATE:

I made like that but i am not happy with this code

```
  var fileList= _term.Childs.Where(r => r.GetType() == typeof(RMFile))
  .OrderBy(o => o.Childs.All(a => a.Properties["ActiveStatus"].Equals("C"))).ToList();
    _term.Childs.RemoveAll(r => r.GetType() == typeof(RMFile));
    _term.Childs.AddRange(fileList);
    _term.Childs = _term.Childs.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Can both of those classes have single parent, eg. RMBase ?, Or just some common members in interface?

Comment: here is definition     public class RMTerm : RMNode<Term>
     public class RMFile : RMNode<FilePart>, IParent      and for the baseclass     public class RMNode<T> : RMCommonNode, IRMNode where T : IRMNodeObject

Comment: I guess you already have your solution. Other option could be creating IRMSort interface with member that for RMFile returns ActiveStatus and class name for RMTerm

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question to add the class definition.